# Running a .net 4.0 WCF data service on a subdomain

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-data-services, wcf-4

I have two domains running my WCF data services:

- a) http://www.domain-a.com/
- b) http://api.domain-b.com/

When I address my service like this:

http://domain-a.com/odata.svc - IT WORKS.

When I address my service like this:

http://www.domain-a.com/odata.svc - I GET THE FOLLOW EXCEPTION:

> Message: Service 'cf.Svc.odata_v0' has
>   zero application (non-infrastructure)
>   endpoints. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no service
>   element matching the service name
>   could be found in the configuration
>   file, or because no endpoints were
>   defined in the service element.
>   ExceptionStackTrace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.EnsureThereAreApplicationEndpoints(ServiceDescription
>   description) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase
>   serviceHost) at

The problem, is that I need moving forward to run my service on:

http://api.domain-b.com/ and I do not have the option to reference it as http://domain-b.com/ because the root domain is already in use.

I even tried downloading the WCF Data Services Toolkit (http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/65119) april release thinking I'd get around the problem with setting up a nice clean route - like:

http://api.domain-b.com/odata

But I'm still getting this error. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

My web.config looks like below - I am also running WCF Rest Services that do not have any issues in the same application.

```
<system.serviceModel> 
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" /> 
  <standardEndpoints> 
    <webHttpEndpoint> 
     <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" 
                       automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpEndpoint> 
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: A svc file needs to be inside an IIS virtual directory - are you sure that your "subdomain" does actually point to a location of an IIS virtual directory?  Also: could you show us your server-side `web.config` that is used for this OData service??

Comment: My sub domain is in it's on root level web application. Web.config looks like this:  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

Comment: I am also running WCF .net Rest Services from the Rest kit which work fine - the thing I'm trying to point out is that the issue doesn't have to do with the subdomain. Because the first domain is failing with a www - which I guess is a sub-domain :) ...

Comment: can you please **update** your original question and put the web.config in there?? Here in comments, it's **really hard** to read.....